# log to one database from multiple instaces of identical jar-file but keep track of which instance logged what using log4j2

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot, log4j2

I have three instances of one Spring Boot jar and they all to log to a single mysql database using `log4j2`. Those jars are identical. Each jar loads an external config file on start, in order to get different service names for each of the three instances.

Now I want to be able to separate the log-entries of the different instances in the database in some way. So far I did try to:

1. log to different tables, based on the external config file.
   It seems I would need to bypass the log4j-api  and directly use the log4j-core functionality. Risky?
2. log to one table, but have a column to separate them.
   How can I do this across threads and for all my used external packges? I looked into markers, but it seems that I would have to get into every thread and set the marker. It does not feel to be the right way to get into every dependency and add that into the code.

For me nothing worked out so far. Am I missing something / Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you may use the MDC https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html in order to follow the solution number 2)

Answer (score 0):

For approach 1. (different tables) I got the following solution (almost) running.

Finally managed to find the right section in the manual:
[Log4j2 Manual - Programmatically Modifying the Current Configuration after Initialization](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#Programmatically_Modifying_the_Current_Configuration_after_Initialization)

As I finished the programmatical configuration of the database appender to change the table name to log to `serverConfig.getName()`. We noticed that a single database may not be the best approach for us. But I would like to share the code to the point I got. Sadly I cant invest more time, so this remains untested :/

```
DatabaseLoggerAppender.java
public class DatabaseLogAppender {

    @Autowired
    private ServerConfig serverConfig;

    public void addDatabaseAppender(Level level) {
        final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();

        ColumnConfig[] columnConfigs = {
                ColumnConfig.createColumnConfig(config, "EVENT_DATE", null, null, "true", null, null),
                ColumnConfig.createColumnConfig(config, "LEVEL", "%level", null, null, null, null),
                ColumnConfig.createColumnConfig(config, "LOGGER", "%logger", null, null, null, null),
                ColumnConfig.createColumnConfig(config, "THREAD", "%thread", null, null, null, null),
                ColumnConfig.createColumnConfig(config, "MESSAGE", "%message", null, null, null, null),
                ColumnConfig.createColumnConfig(config, "THROWABLE", "%xEx{full}", null, null, null, null)
        };
        Appender appender = JdbcAppender.createAppender("databaseAppender", "false", null, ConnectionFactory.Singleton.INSTANCE, "4000", serverConfig.getName(), columnConfigs);
        appender.start();
        config.addAppender(appender);
        config.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender, Level.DEBUG, null);
        ctx.updateLoggers();
    }
}



ConnectionFactory.java
public class ConnectionFactory implements ConnectionSource {
    static interface Singleton {
        final ConnectionFactory INSTANCE = new ConnectionFactory();
    }

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    private ConnectionFactory() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("user", "root");
        properties.setProperty("password", "1Systech2"); // or get properties from some configuration file

        GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection> pool = new GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection>();
        DriverManagerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(
                "jdbc:mysql://192.168.209.236:3306/logs?serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin", properties
        );
        new PoolableConnectionFactory(
                connectionFactory, pool, null, "SELECT 1", 3, false, false, Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
        );

        this.dataSource = new PoolingDataSource(pool);
    }

    /**
     * This should return a new connection every time it is called.
     *
     * @return the SQL connection object.
     * @throws SQLException if a database error occurs.
     */
    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return Singleton.INSTANCE.dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```